# Are Ansible handlers defined in roles ran after the entire playbook or the role?

Tags: ansible

I'm running Ansible 2.0, and I could just run this, but I could also be tricked in to believing something that isn't true by my empirical tests and I can find no documentation to tell me when handlers are supposed to be ran.

If handlers aren't ran at the end of their tasks, this is my conundrum. I've got a playbook with 5 roles in it, I want to add a 6 role to the end that needs to have the handlers of the 4th role completed before it can start.

Is there any way to run Ansible to rely on a handler being completed (i.e. a role being completely completed) before doing something else or am I using handlers wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Handlers are executed:

- at the end of a play (not playbook)
- on executing the `meta: flush_handlers` task

So "*to add a 6 role to the end that needs to have the handlers of the 4th role*" you need:

- either to split the role assignment into separate plays;
- or add a meta task and include the 6th role with [`include_role` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_role_module.html):

  ```
  roles:
    - role4
  tasks:
    - meta: flush_handlers
    - include_role:
        name: role6
  ```

For your use case, I'd suggest the first method as the `include_role` module is still very fresh and there are quirks when using it (see [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171103/ansible-include-role-on-a-loop-running-unexpected-number-of-times)).

---

Moreover, please notice that handlers' names and listen calls are global, so two handlers in separate roles will be in conflict if they had the same name and both roles were assigned in a single play. (ref. [Handlers: Running Operations On Change](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change))

> Handlers [ ] are referenced by a globally unique name, and are notified by notifiers. [ ] a handler, it will run only once, after all of the tasks complete in a particular play.
>
> Handler names and listen topics live in a global namespace.

---

- Empirical proof (run this shell script to confirm handlers are executed at the end of the play - there were contradicting comments and answers here):

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  mkdir -p ./sf831880/roles/role1
  mkdir -p ./sf831880/roles/role1/handlers
  mkdir -p ./sf831880/roles/role1/tasks
  mkdir -p ./sf831880/roles/role2
  mkdir -p ./sf831880/roles/role2/handlers
  mkdir -p ./sf831880/roles/role2/tasks

  cat >./sf831880/roles/role1/tasks/main.yml <<TASKS1_END
  ---
  - name: Always true in role1
    command: echo role1
    notify: handler1
  TASKS1_END

  cat >./sf831880/roles/role2/tasks/main.yml <<TASKS2_END
  ---
  - name: Always true in role2
    command: echo role2
    notify: handler2
  TASKS2_END

  cat >./sf831880/roles/role1/handlers/main.yml <<HANDLERS1_END
  ---
  - name: handler1
    debug:
      msg: "This is a handler in role1"
  HANDLERS1_END

  cat >./sf831880/roles/role2/handlers/main.yml <<HANDLERS2_END
  ---
  - name: handler2
    debug:
      msg: "This is a handler in role2"
  HANDLERS2_END

  cat >./sf831880/playbook.yml <<PLAYBOOK_END
  ---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    connection: local
    roles:
      - role1
      - role2
    tasks:
      - debug:
          msg: "This is a task in a play"
  PLAYBOOK_END

  ansible-playbook ./sf831880/playbook.yml
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

  TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [role2 : Always true in role2] ********************************************
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": "This is a task in a play"
  }

  RUNNING HANDLER [role1 : handler1] *********************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": "This is a handler in role1"
  }

  RUNNING HANDLER [role2 : handler2] *********************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": "This is a handler in role2"
  ```
- Play modified to contain `meta: flush_handlers`:

  ```
  ---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    connection: local
    roles:
      - role1
      - role2
    tasks:
      - meta: flush_handlers
      - debug:
          msg: "This is a task in a play"
  ```

  The result:

  ```
  PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

  TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
  changed: [localhost]

  TASK [role2 : Always true in role2] ********************************************
  changed: [localhost]

  RUNNING HANDLER [role1 : handler1] *********************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": "This is a handler in role1"
  }

  RUNNING HANDLER [role2 : handler2] *********************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": "This is a handler in role2"
  }

  TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
  ok: [localhost] => {
      "msg": "This is a task in a play"
  ```

Answer (score 4):

> Handlers are lists of tasks, not really any different from regular
>   tasks, that are referenced by a globally unique name, and are notified
>   by notifiers. If nothing notifies a handler, it will not run.
>   Regardless of how many tasks notify a handler, it will run only once,
>   after all of the tasks complete in a particular play. [ansible doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html)

1) Handlers that do the same thing should be named the same.
`restart nginx` ALWAYS restarts nginx, not `handler1` and `handler2`

2) Handlers are run at the END of the entire "Play" a play scoped to your sections.

3) I would use the [`register`](https://github.com/JakeDEvans/sf831880/blob/master/roles/role1/tasks/main.yml#L10) and [`when`](https://github.com/JakeDEvans/sf831880/blob/master/roles/role2/tasks/main.yml#L4) functions for tasks that should be restarted, note this var should carry with you.

[Code Source](https://github.com/JakeDEvans/sf831880/blob/master/playbook.yml)

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Play 1"
}

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role2 : Run if change in task c of role 1] *******************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role2 : Always true in role2] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is a task in a play"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [role1 : handler] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is a handler in role1"
}

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Play 2"
}

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role1 : Always true in role1] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role2 : Run if change in task c of role 1] *******************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [role2 : Always true in role2] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is a task in a play"
}

RUNNING HANDLER [role1 : handler] **********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is a handler in role1"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=20   changed=14   unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Lots of ways to do the same task.  Handlers were designed to prevent restarting the same process multiple times, such as multiple changes to a nginx server that has websites, ssl certs, and other tasks that need service restarts.

Comment: You are quoting "*run only once, after all of the tasks complete in a particular play*" and then claim something completely different "*run a task at the end of every role*". Your claim is also different from the reality.

Comment: no you misunderstand, if I call the same handler from the server role 4 times from meta. it only runs once

Comment: The question is clear: **when** are the handlers run? Not how many times they are run. And they are run at the end of a play, not at the end of a role. Period. You are a third person claiming otherwise, even though you did it after I posted my answer with examples showing this claim is false.

Comment: and my answer is, use tasks not handlers for items that must be restarted within their role.

Comment: @techraf there you are.